# Why are there shadows of previous notifications on my phone.the shadows are only on my home screen and they disappear whenever I go to a diffrent app

Tags: android

[image]

why are there shadows ??

i tried to search a way to turn it off in settings but couldn't find one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Spamming letters to reach the minimum word limit isn’t a good idea. Pls read: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If this is a photo of your screen (not a screen shot) then most likely these are symbols burned-in into your OLED display. This is a common problem of OLED displays.

Comment: It is not a photo and infact is a screen shot

Comment: I found out the reason thank you for commenting